# Stack per two columns and two measures

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have data that looks something like this:

```
order_id     Product_A    Product_B    Price_Product_A    Price_Product_B
100          Pen          Notebook     1.5                3
101          Bag          Watch        10                 12
```

I need it to look like this:

```
order_id    product    price
100         Pen        1.5
100         Notebook   3
101         Bag        10
101         Watch      12
```

How can I use stack() and unstack() for this? I used it so fat only for one numeric measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a convenient function for this, `wide_to_long`:

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, ['Product','Price_Product'], i='order_id', j='subtype', sep = '_', suffix = '\D+')
```

output:

```
                     Product        Price_Product
order_id    subtype     
100         A        Pen            1.5
101         A        Bag            10.0
100         B        Notebook       3.0
101         B        Watch          12.0
```

The same can be achieved with `melt` and `unstack`, which could be of instructional value. A somewhat tricky bit is to split `'variable'` into two parts, the root and the suffix, something `wide_to_long` helps you with. For your example case this can look like this:

```
df1 = df.melt(id_vars = 'order_id')
df1['cat'] = df1['variable'].str[:-2]     # you may have to tweak this for your actual data
df1['subtype'] = df1['variable'].str[-1:] # you may have to tweak this for your actual data
(df1.drop(columns = 'variable')
    .set_index(['order_id','subtype','cat'])
    .unstack()
    .droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
    .reset_index()
)
```

Comment: wide_to_long worked!

Answer (score 1):

I would simply create two dataframes: one for product A and one for product B. Then set the column names for both and append them like this:

```
df1 = df[['order_id', 'Product_A', 'Price_Product_A']]
df2 = df[['order_id', 'Product_B', 'Price_Product_B']]

df1.columns = ['order_id', 'product', 'price']
df2.columns = ['order_id', 'product', 'price']

df = df1.append(df2)
df
```

Output:

```
    order_id    product price
0   100 Pen       1.5
1   101 Bag       10.0
0   100 Notebook  3.0
1   101 Watch     12.0
```

Comment: It's indeed a good solution, but I'd like to generalize on more than one column rather than just "order id" and more than 2 products. I could create n dfs, but I think this can be done with stack and unstack methods.